# using Amazon S3 with the paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

Is it good practice to simply post my access key id/secret access key directly into the model? For example...

```
has_attached_file :pic, :s3_credentials => { 
   :bucket => 'MY_BUCKET_NAME', 
   :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename", 
   :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename", 
   :access_key_id => "12345Secret#blahblah", 
   :secret_access_key => "12345###" 
}
```

This actually works, however, when I duplicate the image to another model...it doesnt upload.

i.e. `@other_user.pic = @user.pic` (to copy the image to the other User)

For instance if the image that works is: `S3Amazon/pic/01.working.jpg`

the copied image has a one number increase in the file like so: `S3Amazon/pic/02.working.jpg`

This image does not open, been searching all week for a way to make this work.

Comment: your question is not clear. You once say  `duplicate the image to another model` and next sentence you say `copy the image to the other User`. Which one is your case? I would like to believe all `user`s share the same model.

Comment: You are neither copying or duplicating in this case you just have 2 instance variables referencing the same object. have you tried cloning such as `@other_user.pic = @user.pic.clone`

Comment: I just tried using .clone, didnt work. What I exactly mean is that I created a simple inbox/messaging system btw different Users a la facebook messaging.  When one User sends another User a message with an attached picture, I want that same picture to be uploaded into the other User’s inbox.  How is that created?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@other_user.pic = @user.pic
@other_user.save!
```

And make sure, if you're doing this from the console, that you do `@other_user.reload` before checking urls